# Stereochemistry of C as non-chiral centre

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

When a C of a molecule is not a chiral centre, the spatial orientation of its substituent group doesn't affect its stereochemical specification, does it?

Ex: [image]

Comment: Also note that hashed or wedged bond should not be used for nonstereogenic atoms. Plain bonds should be used for nonstereogenic atoms, even if the substituents are not physically coplanar.

Comment: Actually it depends on the message that must be conveyed. @Loong◆ Geometry can/must be detailed if necessary. Which is not the case for most drawing of reactions, this is true.